# How to send extra argument with pre_delete signal?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to delete a model (House) but before that, insert it in deleted table.
so far:

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=House)
def delete_house(sender, instance, **kwargs):
  reason = kwargs.get('delete_reason', '')
  if sender == House:
    deleted_house = DeletedHouse(doc_code=instance.doc_code,
                               tell=instance.tell,
                               address=instance.address,
                                delete_reason=reason)
    deleted_house.save()

  for member in instance.child_set:
    m = DeletedMember(first_name=member.first_name,
                    last_name=member.last_name,
                    house=deleted_house
                    )
    m.save()
```

House will delete all children (CASCADE). so I have to save deleted house and children in pre_delete. The problem is I do not know how to pass delete_reason in kwargs to my method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass it with instance

```
# before you call delete
house.delete_reason = 'banana'

# and then you can retrieve it in your function
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=House)
def delete_house(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    reason = getattr(instance, 'delete_reason', '')
    ...
```

Also why are you checking for `sender == House` if you set it in decorator params?

Comment: Why I did not thinked of this